# Typescript 9.5+; import bootstrap into an AMD module to use jquery extensions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, typescript, amd, definitelytyped

all.

I'm using `require.js`, and TypeScript in AMD mode, and I'm having trouble importing Bootstrap into my scripts. I've got import statements like this;

```
import $ = require('jquery');
import ko = require('knockout');
import bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

And it's converting it into this JavaScript;

```
define(["require", "exports", 'jquery', 'knockout'], 
    function(require, exports, $, ko) {
    ...
});
```

Notice that Bootstrap isn't in the list of required modules. That's because TypeScript is being 'clever', noting that I'm never referencing the Bootstrap import like this;

```
// this never appears in my code
bootstrap.blah()
```

And dropping the 'unused' bootstrap import. In normal cases, this is fine, but bootstrap actually extends jQuery, adding things like

```
// bootstrap adds jQuery plugins like modal;
$(selector).modal()
```

So by dropping the include, jQuery is no longer extended with `modal()` etc, and my code fails.

What I need is a way to tell TypeScript that it really does need to include the `'bootstrap'`module in the list of required modules.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of this (poorly documented) little trick, by adding the following to the top of your file:

```
/// <amd-dependecy path="bootstrap">
```

This will add `bootstrap` in the list of AMD dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What you may need is a require.config section, and specify a shim for boostrap.
In this way, both jquery and boostrap export their functions to any $ or jquery selector.

something like :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.7.2',
        'boostrap': 'lib/boostrap',
    }, 
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        boostrap: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```